# Value from form input does not be transmit by the submit button. How can I fix that?

Tags: javascript, forms, asp.net-core

i try to add fields in a form by clicking a button. The fields appear and the validation works either.
The problem is, that the value of these input fields isn't transmitted by the submit button of the form.

The framework is ASP.NET Core-Web-App (Model View Controller) with .Net 5.

I add the fields with the following code.

```
 putMoreFields.addEventListener("click", function () {
    
    myTextField.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',
        '<label asp-for="ContactMail" class="form-label"></label> <input type="email" class="form-control" asp-for="ContactMail" placeholder="name@example.com" required> <span asp-validation-for="ContactMail" class="text-danger"></span> </div> <div class="invalid-feedback"> Bitte geben Sie eine Mail-Adresse ein. </div> </div >')
    myTextField.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',
        '<label asp-for="ContactMail" class="form-label"></label> <input type="date" class="form-control" asp-for="ContactMail" placeholder="dd.mm.jjjj" required> <span asp-validation-for="ContactMail" class="text-danger"></span> </div> <div class="invalid-feedback"> Bitte geben Sie eine Mail-Adresse ein. </div> </div >')
    
})
```

Can someone help me?

Best regards

JuRi-2020

Comment: You can change your code:`asp-for="ContactMail"` to  `name="ContacMail"`

Comment: Hi,any update about this case? Is that work?

Comment: @Yinqiu But I need asp-for="ContactMail" for communicate with the modle doesn't I?

Comment: You just need change all the `asp-for="ContactMail"` to `name="ContacMail"`,then you can submit your form to do a test.

Comment: I create a form where someone can fill in information.

Comment: Have you try it?By the way,you have two fileds both use `asp-for="ContactMail"`.That will cause binding issue.

Comment: It is incorrect for you to insert `asp-for` directly, it will not be recognized as `html code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need change all the code

```
asp-for="ContactMail"
```

to

```
 name="ContacMail"
```